# Git bash - connection to the repository and last commit edition

Tags: git, bash, github, github-desktop

With the help of the program GitHub Desktop I made a committing project on GitHub
https://zapodaj.net/394446cec1850.png.html,
but I forgot to add one more sentence to the commita description. I want to edit this commita, but with GitHub Desktop I can't manage, so I want to use git bash. However, I don't know how to connect with the repository, the sanction is on address `C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services` and in git bush makes an error, because it is not in the repository https://zapodaj.net/30b69c3ce1606.png.html.

How to enter this repository so that I can use commands?

```
git commit --amend
```

Comment: `cd` into the the folder where your repository is

Comment: `cd C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services` will put you in the right folder

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a git bash open, you should make a cd using unix-style path:

```
cd /c/Users/Jonatan/Documents/GitHub/REST-Web-Services
git status
git commit --amend
```